# jquery ui slider .val() allways 0

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider, jquery-ui-slider

```
 $('#spicy').hide().after('<div class="slider" id="spicy_s"></div><div class="sliderT">-</div>');
        $('#spicy_s'). slider({
            value:$('#spicy').val(),
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            step: 5,
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
                                $('#spicy').val(ui.value);
                                if(ui.value > 50){
                                    $('#spicy_s').next('.sliderT').css('color','#00a500').html(ui.value+'<span style="font-size:12px">/100</span>');
                                }else{
                                    $('#spicy_s').next('.sliderT').css('color','red').html(ui.value+'<span style="font-size:12px">/100</span>');
                                }
            }
    });
```

the input is hidden, the slider is shown, but on submit its value is allways 0

Comment: more information would be helpful like what your are trying to do and some sample html

Comment: to what element is 'id' spicy refer to? is it hidden input field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve the slider's value using the the `value()` method described in the jQuery UI documentation [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#method-value). When the slider changes, you can use something like this to store the new value where you need it:

```
var value = $('#spicy_s').slider('value');
```